# .each Loop to Change the href of an Anchor tag inside a Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm stuck where first i need to find on the grid the Text whether it is "Joined" or "Join"
then if it is join the anchor tags Href will be `"/User/JoinEvent?eventId=@item.EventId&eventdateid=@item.EventDateId"`

and when it is "Joined"  the anchor tags Href will be `"/User/DeleteEventDate?userEventId=@item.UserEventId"` 
using Jquery

this is my trial but its all not working because before i want the "Joined" to be disabled

`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#btnEdit').text("Joined")) {
        $('#btnEdit').prop('disabled', "disabled"); 
    }
    else {
        $('#btnEdit').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

`

`<td>
                        <a href="/User/JoinEvent?eventId=@item.EventId&eventdateid=@item.EventDateId" id="btnEdit" class="k-button" style="text-decoration: none;">
                            @item.IsJoined</a>
                    </td>`

My Trial

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var txt = $('#btnEdit').text()
        if (txt === "Joined") {
            $('#btnEdit').prop('href', "/User/DeleteEventDate?userEventId=@item.UserEventId");

        }
        else {
        $('#btnEdit').prop('href', "/User/JoinEvent?eventId=@item.EventId&eventdateid=@item.EventDateId");

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var txt = $('#btnEdit').text()
    if (txt === "Joined") {
        $('#btnEdit').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#btnEdit').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

---

Problem

```
$('#btnEdit').text("Joined") --> you are setting text to Joined
```

and

```
if ($('#btnEdit').text("Joined")) --> if condition will always be true
```

Solution

```
if($('#btnEdit').text() === "Joined") --> check if text is Joined
```

---

To change `a` tag `href` use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$('el').prop('href','value');
```

Comment: sir, how can i change it to change the anchor tags Href?

Comment: sir, There was an error showing that @item does not exist in the ff context?

Comment: Sir still not working. . . Tried both suggestions but failed Posted my <a href>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if ($('#btnEdit').text("Joined"))` I think you mean `if ($('#btnEdit').text() == "Joined")`

Calling jQuery's text method with an argument will set the text of that node to that.

Comment: sir, how can i change it to change the anchor tags Href?

Comment: looks like @TusharGupta already answered this question for you

Comment: Sir still not working. . . Tried both suggestions but failed 
Posted my `<a href>`

Comment: Is it possible that txt does not equal "Joined"? Have you tried putting a console.log or alert in that block to make sure it's getting executed?

Comment: Sir i think i need to loop it because it is in a Datagrid because the alert message appear once only, can you halp me looping it?

Comment: I see, if you are generating a bunch of `a` tags with the same id (btnEdit) you are going to have issues. Is that the case?

Comment: I think yes, i have added the Id with the @item.EventDateId but it says that the context in not defined , thats my error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41595/discussion-between-ren-tao-and-rob-m)